# standalone expo app with VPN turned on ( the VPN on android device ) - adb reverse tcp issue

Tags: android, react-native, networking, expo, adb

I'm developing react native app with expo and I have the development build on android device works well but when I turn on VPN on the android device the app get disconnected to the metro ,
I need to keep app connected along with VPN turned on but how to do that ?

**update**

**the result I get** when try to start my app while vpn is on (on android device ) :

immediately i get **error loading app ,connection reset**, and i connot connect to the server at all .

and when I turn vpn on after my app get connected to the server ,

I'm getting in console :

> Cannot connect to the Metro.
> Try the following to fix the issue:

> Ensure that the Metro server is running and available on the same network
> Ensure that your device/emulator is connected to your machine and has USB debugging enabled - run 'adb devices' to see a list of connected devices

> If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device
> If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server - e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081

URL: 192.168.1.4:8081

**what I tried**
**update 2** after abundant research

1- enable USB debugging and connect device via usb

2- adb kill-server & adb start-server

3- adb tcpip 5555

4- disconnect usb

5- adb connect <phone's IP>

adb reverse successfully done ,I got
`connected to 192.168.1.3:5555`

but when I run

npx expo start --localhost --android

**[ADB] Couldn't reverse port 8081: adb.exe: error: more than one device/emulator**

**Environment** :

Expo managed workflow
sdk 50

OS: Windows 10

standalone app

I have a full internet access and the vpn on android and computer  is psiphon

Comment: @Robert I updated my question and what I got in console

Comment: If your VPN is active your phone is no longer on your Wifi but on the VPN, thus you have to use the adb reverse way as mentioned in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed , it's just about the wrong port I was trying to use 'port 5555' ,
so I could make it work ,the steps as following :

1_ enable USB debugging and connect device to the laptop via USB cable

2- adb kill-server & adb start-server

> - daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
> - daemon started successfully

3- adb tcpip 5037

4- adb connect <phone's IP>

5- adb kill-server

6- npx expo start --localhost --android

and it successfully worked .